# Recurring notification in Outlook, Google or iOS calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I'm trying to add a recurring notification to any of these calendars (Outlook, Google or iOS) that follows the rule:

> Is triggered in the first Tuesday or first Thursday after 20th of each month.

That's mostly because I always forget to pay some of my monthly taxes. :D

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for Google calendar is super easy. However, I'm not very familiar with ios.

When creating an event, double click on it to go to the more advanced settings. Under the time boxes you'll see a checkbox "Repeat" this pops up a new window in which you can configure when, how often and exactly the recurrence of the event as such

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd add a picture, but I need more rep :(

Comment: Just add a link, someone will come along an turn it into a picture (in fact, just add a comment having @soandos in it, and I will do it for you).

Comment: Thanks, Jaguilar. Unfortunately doesn't quite work as i would like. I can set, let's say `Monthly on the third Thursday`. The problem is that next month this means 20, other month 15 and so on. Doesn't really follow my requirements :(

Comment: I see no way for achieving this in Google Cal. You could always put a reminder on the 20th and go from there.